# Exclude the parent custom post-type posts only

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, children, exclude

Not sure if this is possible without some form of hard-coding but I have a custom post-type called 'city'. Within the 'city' post-type I have some parent post (e.g. England, America and China) and some child posts (London, Washington DC and Beijing).

I have a query that displays all of the posts under 'city'. But for this particular query I'd like to actually ignore ANY parent posts (ie. England, America and China) and only display child posts (London, Washington and Beijing).

Here is the way I am coding my query:

```
<?php $city = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'city', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 )); ?>
                            <?php while ($city->have_posts() ) : $city->the_post(); ?>
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

So is this possible? I would have thought that doing the opposite is more of a popular question (displaying only the parents and excluding the children) but I'm hoping that my problem is possible!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the codex for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters), the solution might be to use the `post_parent` as the id of the top level post. But as there are a whole lotta top level cpts in your case, I think this solution should help you: [How to display only top level posts in loop via WP_Query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29897/how-to-display-only-top-level-posts-in-loop-via-wp-query).

**Update:**

```
<?php
    $all = get_posts(array('post_type'=> 'city', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
    $parents = array();
    foreach ($all as $single)
    {
        $kids = get_children($single->ID);  
        if(isset($kids) && !empty($kids) && count($kids) >= 1)
        {
            $parents[] = $single->ID;
        }
    }

    $args = array('post_type' => 'city', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post__not_in' => $parents );

    $city = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($city->have_posts() ) : $city->the_post();
            echo get_the_title()."<br />";
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This is a long cut, but it works. Just make sure you check if the $parents array is not empty before including it in the query.

Comment: Seems as though there's an error with the solutions code when I paste into my functions.php:

The code: [Click here](http://pastebin.com/gFGkT0vG)

Comment: Did you replace 'my_post_type' with 'city'? Did it for you: http://pastebin.com/M8LHc5rF

Comment: Yeh I replaced it already, and I'm talking that code and placing it into my functions.php file - but I get an error (blank white page) on my entire site when I add the code.

Is there something else I should be doing in the actual template page's file?

Comment: Nope, there must be a parse error or something. Please turn on the debug mode and check the error. Debug mode: Edit `wp-config.php` and look for `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`, change it to to it to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. Save this file and visit the errored page again, you'll know the error. Tell me the error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in /home/farmpro1/public_html/test_server/wtc/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php on line 717

Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in /home/farmpro1/public_html/test_server/wtc/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php on line 717

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_get_posts() (previously declared in /home/farmpro1/public_html/test_server/wtc/wp-content/themes/WorldTimeClock/functions.php:298) in /home/farmpro1/public_html/test_server/wtc/wp-content/themes/WorldTimeClock/functions.php on line 346

Comment: So @Rutwick Gangurde there is conflict with my seo plugin

Comment: No Friend! Change the function name in the above code! That'll solve your problem!

Comment: Gandurde - The problem is, this is doing the opposite to what I am trying to achieve. I want to display the CHILDREN only, not the PARENTS. The code in that solution displays the PARENTS ONLY, and excludes the children :)

Comment: Then you might have to use a long cut. Use `get_posts` to get the parent cpts first, then loop over them to get their children.

Comment: Apologies but I'm not sure exactly how to do this. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Sure... Just tell me a thing... What if a post doesn't have any children, should I exclude it?

Comment: If a post doesn't have any children it should be excluded yes. Thanks a lot @Rutwick_Gangurde :)

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want, I think, is the `posts_where` filter, which allows you to add additional `WHERE` clauses to the SQL query that `get_posts` generates.  This will save you the trip to the database to fetch only parent posts.

The hooked function will receive two arguments: the `WHERE` clause itself and the query object.  Check to see if the query is for the `city` post type, then modify the where clause from there.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse29897_no_parents', 10, 2 );
function wpse29897_no_parents( $where, $query )
{
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && 'city' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] )
    {
        if( '' != $where )
        {
            $where .= ' AND post_parent !=  0';
        }
        else
        {
            $where .= ' post_parent != 0';
        }
    }
    return $where;
}
```

I'm guessing that you don't want this to happen for EVERY query that involves the `city` post type, however.  So you best bet is probably to stick the `add_filter` call right above where you're creating the new WP_Query object.  Then stick the `wpse29897_no_parents` function in your `functions.php` file or a plugin.

```
<?php 
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse29897_no_parents', 10, 2 );
$city = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'city', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ));
while ($city->have_posts() ) : $city->the_post(); 
?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You could even remove the filter after your loop just to be sure.

```
<?php remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse29897_no_parents', 10, 2 ); ?>
```